# Importing tab-delimited text file into openrefine

Tags: text, line-breaks, openrefine

I have a medium-sized tab-delimited .txt file - about 40k lines. When I import to Openrefine, line 406 puts all the rest of the content - the whole 40,000 lines, into a single cell in column 13 of that line.

I've tried grep-serching the invisibles in two different text editors (Sublime Text 2 & TextWrangler), and everything looks like it should.

I've also tried using Excel to convert to csv, and that actually works, but:

1. it's an inelegant workaround,
2. it has trouble with diacriticals, and
3. I don't want to spend ay more time resolving it in Excel anyway

I tried excepting the offending line with 10 lines on either side, and that throws the same problem.

[Here are those 21 lines](http://mvabl.com/public/data_excerpt.txt), copied directly from TextWrangler. (I can copy from Terminal output if that makes any difference.)

Any help, as always, is very much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

I see. The problem is related to the quotations marks. Try importing your file by unchecking "Quotation marks are used to enclose cells containing column separators".

[image]

The empty columns in my screenshot are due to the fact that your file sometimes has two or three tabs as a separator. You can delete them easily after import using "reorder / remove columns"

[image]

Comment: you're right - when i copy-pasted from the file to the post window, the tabs got translated to spaces.

here's a link to the file: http://mvabl.com/mvabl.com/public/data_excerpt.txt


again, this is the "offending" line + 10 lines on either side. so the bad line is #11

I understand @Ettore's suggestions, but they're not actually applicable.

Comment: @SteveS Sorry, I get a "URL Not Find" when I click the link.

Comment: sorry. i had mvabl.com twice. this should work:

http://mvabl.com/public/data_excerpt.txt

Answer (score 0):

**Solved It!** Well, sort of. It turns out that Column 13 had text that included double-quotes *within the text itself* (In other words, ***not*** having to do with delimiters at all).

For now, I'm just going to remove those quotes in the entire file, which does work - I tested it. **I'd rather figure out how to keep the quotes as part of the text. Tried escaping them with /, but that didn't work.

Thanks SO Community. Especially @Ettore.